# Suggestion to help Waterproof around storm door

Tags: trim, siding, door-frame

My storm door was not being supported very well so I removed it attempting to fix it. I found the top corner trim and siding rotting pretty bad. I am almost done removing all of the soft wood.

[image: house trim]

Besides just replacing the rotting peices, caulking, and painting should i be adding some other sort of waterproofing material while I am in here?

House was built in 1979 in USA, Colorado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a considerable lack of flashing.

Adding it after the fact is going to require more taking things apart, in order to get flashing where it should be.

I'd suggest dropping  **flashing around a doorway** into your search engine of choice, or borrowing a book or video from your library. It's a bit much to cover properly here (*but if someone wants to take a stab at it without plagiarizing a source, be my guest...*)

Comment: the trap is set